# When would I write a non-tail recursive function in Scala?

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, stack-overflow

Since non-tail recursion calls use stack frames like Java does, I'd think you'd be using it very sparingly, if at all. This seems however severely restrictive given it's one of the most important tools.

When can I use non-tail recursion functions? Also, are there plans to remove the memory restriction in the future?

Comment: Do you mean non-tail recursive but still recursive functions/methods? Those come up quite often actually. Consider using recursion to walk a tree, it's most easily done with non-tail recursive recursion.

Comment: Almost identical question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630692/how-usable-is-non-tail-recursive-recursion-in-scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same situations where it would be safe in Java, where the dataset you are working with never grows huge and the performance isn't critical/hot path of your app.

Also, IMHO, there are times when the clarity of non tail recursion version of an algorithm is way better than the tail recursive version.